# Execute application using mvn clean install

Tags: spring, maven, cucumber

I am working on a simple spring boot application (created from spring initializr contains web mega-dependency).

I added also Cucumber dependencies for acceptance test.

When I run `mvn clean install` it runs directly the cucumber test, but me I want to run the app before tests (And why not stop the app after the tests terminate).

I tried maven exec plugin but it does not work:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
  <executions><execution>
    <goals><goal>java</goal></goals>
  </execution></executions>
  <configuration>
    <mainClass>org.dhappy.test.NeoTraverse</mainClass>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Skipping tests

If there is a need to skip tests and just compile and package the application, you can set the skipTests property as follows:

```
mvn install -DskipTests
```

### Application execution

If you want to run the application, you can use the exec plugin. There are two flavours ("goals" really): one runs the package application and the other runs a Java class. If you know the class name, you can run that plugin as follows:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.dhappy.test.NeoTraverse"
```

### Integration testing

Finally, if you want to run the application first before you can run the tests, you are actually not doing unit testing. Your tests in this case are perhaps integration and not unit tests. The actual details would vary depending on whether your application has complex needs such as a database and a web server.

Integration testing happens at a different "phase" in maven lifecycle.

In short, you need to rename your Java test classes something other than `*Test.java` so that maven surefire plugin ignores your tests. You then need to include `maven-failsafe-plugin` so that integration testing happens.

Answer (score 1):

You want to perform these steps:

- Start the application
- Run a set of tests
- Stop the application

Starting and stopping the application is one thing and could be done in the `<phase>pre-integration-test</phase>` and `<phase>post-integration-test</phase>`. Integration testing is done in the `<phase>integration-test</phase>`

You want to read and understand https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html. Specifically, look at the **Using jetty and maven-failsafe-plugin** example.